# QGIS delimited text layer is not visible

Tags: qgis, layers

I have a txt file that looks as follows:

```
28.4623846099669    -81.5099918874859   -0.48895188341136
28.4623846099669    -81.5100021171702   -0.476651706025201
28.4623825951648    -81.5099918874859   -0.494750711657957
28.4623811337818    -81.5100021171702   -0.482676411934648
28.4623846099669    -81.5099820433032   -0.51062253969797
28.4623846099669    -81.5100123468545   -0.470347391834316
28.4623810126804    -81.5100123468545   -0.474315518252411
28.4623846099669    -81.5100225765388   -0.473898857410823
28.4623810126804    -81.5100225765388   -0.477238534979527
28.4623846099669    -81.510032806223    -0.489113170179998
28.4623823546772    -81.510032806223    -0.49147295915013
28.4623846099669    -81.5100430359073   -0.515053009095062
28.462383749632 -81.5100430359073   -0.511664667477035
28.4623846099669    -81.5100468762527   -0.527126577494165
28.4623936031829    -81.5099509687488   -0.486596074295029
28.4623936031829    -81.5099611984331   -0.487507502035967
28.4623934556977    -81.5099509687488   -0.486385570973241
```

The coordinates are located around 9000 Bay Hill Boulevard, Orlando, FL 32819, United States of America.

I want to create a layer from the text file. First, I start a new project. The CRS in this project is *EPSG:4326*. This is visible in my screen in the low-right part of the screen.

Next, I go to `Layer` --> `Add layer` --> `Add Delimited Text Layer`

[image]

However, the layer is not visible.

What am I doing wrong?

A lot of answers here mention that there could be a mismatch between CRS of the project and the dataset but in my case its both *EPSG:4326*.

Comment: At least the coordinates do not seem to be expressed as DMS. And for QGIS x=longitude and y=latitude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the X (longitude) & Y (latitude) coordinates reversed. And the coordinates are DD (decimal degrees) not DMS (degrees, minutes, seconds)

[image]

[image]